# Recording data from one excel sheet to another automatically, but keeping even if deleted from master sheet

Tags: excel

I have an excel spreadsheet I use to keep track of candidates I'm hiring at work.

This spreadsheet is becoming very large so what I want to do is have 2 sheets:

1) `current candidates` (candidates who are currently in the process)

2) `historic candidates` (candidates who are currently in the process and candidates who have previously been in the process).

I could manually add to both sheets, but what I'd like to do is manually update only the `current candidates` sheet, have the `historic candidates` sheet automatically update with that data, but when I delete data from the `current candidates` sheet I want it to remain in the `historic candidates` sheet.

It's the retaining data in `historic candidates` I'm having most difficulty in finding a solution to.

Comment: This is not easy to do as for something to automatically update it has to reference the data on the current sheet so when you delete it, the referenced data will go too.  The only solution I can see is to categorize the candidates on the current sheet and then run a macro every so often that automatically moves the "historic" records to the historic sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need a macro to do this. It's the only realistic method to actually copy data between different locations, rather than just linking the values.

The good news is that a macro that does this automatically as you enter data in the "Current" sheet would not be difficult to create, and there are many free guides available to walk you through the process.

If you don't want to go the macro route, the alternative would be to work backwards - put all of the data into a single sheet (the "Historical Candidates" sheet), with a flag you can change to mark whether they're a current candidate or not, then use any of the various tools available to filter data to pull a list of current candidates over to another sheet.